# Can't remove line at top of html table

Tags: html-table, border, borderless

I'm building a site that includes a table in the middle of the homepage, and I can't seem to get a line (looks like an `<hr>` line) to disappear from the top of it. Here's a link to the page http://marccary.com/test and here's the code I'm using for the table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="none">
  <colgroup border="none">
    <col span="1" width="400" >
    <col span="1" width="400" >
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td height="225" width="600"><p align="center">&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<iframe width="400" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F84936057%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-4zQJw&show_artwork=true&secret_url=true"></iframe><br><span style="font-size:20px;"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/marccary" style="color:#white;">Marc Cary on Soundcloud>></a></span></p></td>
    <td height="225" width="600"><p align="center">&nbsp;
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/j9GhIaaEC6c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<span style="font-size:20px;"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/marccary" style="color:#white;">Marc Cary's YouTube channel>></a></savaipan></p></td></tr></table>
```

I've gone into my CSS and tried to make sure there are no borders on tables. I've put the following code into my CSS stylesheet:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: none !important;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
caption,
th {
    border-bottom: none;
    border: none;
    border-top: none;
}
td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
tr {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
```

Still no luck. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: change `border="none"` to `border="0"`

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSS setting:

```
.entry-content td, .comment-content td {
   border-top: 1px solid #EDEDED;
}
```

Thats the border you see.

This CSS

```
border-top: none;
border: none;
border-bottom: none;
```

can be shortened to just

```
border: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
hr {
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

It seems you're using a CMS software to develop your site and the template you're using is actually putting an `<hr>` at

```
<div id="page" ...>
    <header id="masthead" ...>
        <hgroup ...>
        <nav id="site-navigation" ...>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <div id="main" ...>
    <footer ...>
</div>
```